# Odds of being pick for a product?

Tags: probability

I was picked to do a product review and I was able to find out the number of people that had applied and how many were actually picked from those that applied. I'm trying so hard to figure out what the odds of getting were, that my brain is breaking(not at all good at math)So here are the numbers. There were 200 of the products to distribute and 9000 people applied. What were the odds of any one person being chosen to recieve the product?

This is just me being very curious but not having the skills needed to figure this out for myself. Please humor me and help me with this mystery. Thank you.

Comment: You say you know "how many were actually picked from those that applied", but you do not revel that number (at least you do not say that either number you give is that number).

Comment: Does every (accepted) reviewer get exactly one product? If yes, I think the probability is simply $\frac{200}{9000}\approx 2.22~\%$.